# Slow installation of applications in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: 11.04, software-center, apt, performance

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 desktop and I am in the process of learning. I want to install some applications from the Ubuntu Software Center, but the installation process is quite long and slow. With the Ubuntu Software Center, I can only install and download one application for a time. So I want to ask is there a way to speed up the process of installing software through the Ubuntu Software Center, like a multi-tasking program?

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61719/why-the-software-center-doesnt-allow-multiple-dowloads/61729#61729

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the Ubuntu Community!.

The installation times depends on several factors:

- Download Speed
- Size of Packages
- PC Hardware
- Etc.

You can only install 1 package at the time, because that's how [`APT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) was created.

Answer (score 1):

Software Center is slow, so please close Software Center and use the quickest way to install packages, the terminal: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open and to install applications type:

`sudo apt-get install name_of_package1 name_of_package2 ...`

Give your user password when requested. You will not see any password screen when you type the password, so type then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Another way that's quicker than the Software Center for installing packages is to use Synaptic.

Comment: Note that it would be advisable to run `sudo apt-get update` to get updated package information prior to installing through the terminal. Also, you'll still be using the `apt` package manager to download and install your applications, so while you might see a performance boost it can still only install one package at a time.

Comment: The software center is slow because apt is slow.

Answer (score -1):

## Lubuntu Software Center

Maybe you would like to install [lubuntu software center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lubuntu-software-center). It's the lightweight ubuntu software center, and it is much more simple too.

#### To install it:

- **Slow but graphical *Ubuntu Software Center* way**:
  click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lubuntu-software-center)

---

- **Fast but terminal way**:
  You'll have to type or copy-paste:

  ```
   sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center
  ```

[image: Lubuntu Software Center]

Comment: This is a very old question, and has nothing to do with the actual software center. The original post was asking why you could only install 1 package at a time.