# Why does update-manager download and install updates separately?

Tags: update-manager

Is there a reason why the update manager will download all updates, and then start installing once every single update has been downloaded? Wouldn't it be faster to start installing updates once one particular update is downloaded?

This is not a duplicate of [why-the-software-center-doesnt-allow-multiple-downloads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61719/why-the-software-center-doesnt-allow-multiple-downloads) as that explains why the software center doesn't allow for multiple packages to be downloaded and installed concurrently. My question pertains to why the downloading and installation of multiple packages (updates) is not done concurrently. For example, the update manager will download all updates, then begin to install updates once EVERY package has been downloaded. Why wouldn't it start installing updates as they're downloaded, in parallel to downloading other updates?

(Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this question, I just couldn't really think of a better place to ask)

Comment: It's very logical. What don't do it like that? Will be useless install a supplementary package for a main package that wont be used until the main package is updated. That is just one example of how impractical it could result.

Comment: @Lucio That's not really a problem at all. The packages could just be downloaded in the proper order.

Comment: @EliahKagan You're right, is not a *problem*, is just not useful.

Comment: @Lucio It would be quite useful. The whole updating process would complete faster.

Comment: @EliahKagan Maybe you're right. I can't understand very well the point. I though that this question is about the update-manager and the other question about the software-center. Quite different for me..

Comment: @Straemer Are you sure this isn't a duplicate? The question this has been duped to is about why packages aren't installed while other packages are still downloading. That seems exactly the same as what you're asking (going by the paragraph you just added). Are you asking why packages aren't installed why other packages *are installed*?

Comment: I have to agree with @EliahKagan on this one.  The question that this one was marked as a dupe of answers what we believe is what you're asking (based on what you've added, that CONFIRMS that initial assessment).

Comment: That still isn't quite the same question. That question pertains as to why 2 packages will download and install separately. I am asking why all packages are downloaded, and then all are installed. For example,

$(sudo apt-get install A B)

would download A, then download B (It might download both in parallel, I'm not sure), and then start installing A after both A and B have downloaded. Why does A not start installing while B is still downloading?

Comment: @Straemer And that's exactly what that question is asking. From the question: "Or instead why the software center doesn't download an app while the other is installing"