# Why doesn't apt install packages as they're downloaded?

Tags: apt

Why doesn't apt download sources in order of dependency and install as they've finished downloading? Meaning, download and install in parallel. It seems like a lot of time could be saved this way. By the time the last package is downloaded, which won't take any longer than usual, all or most of the rest of the installing should be finished. If it isn't, what's downloaded would wait in queue like normal. If a lower dependency fails to install it could abort the install like normal, without having downloaded every other package you have specified as well.

It seems like this shouldn't be an original idea, it's very apparent. I'm wondering if there's a reason this is avoided?

Comment: Because nobody is interested in implementing it. See [this teenage  wishlist bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=97872). Voting to close as a bug report.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61719/why-the-software-center-doesnt-allow-multiple-downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something looks weird and illogical always ask 2 questions:

1. Where is the lover?
2. Where is the money?

**Answers:**

1. Nowhere! ;-)
2. Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu) makes its money by selling support contracts.

   - Companies take support contracts.
   - Companies have big Internet pipes
   - Canonical and its customers want as little problems as possible ("Stable")

**So although it would be *more efficient* to download-install in parallel, it's *more robust* to download first and then install.**

Comment: And as you're a reputation 6 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Although the answer is frustrating, I accept it. Just for kicks, I'm attempting to rewrite apt-fast (a wrapper for apt/aptitude that downloads packages using aria2c/axel before installing) to do just this. Not quite there yet, but it's coming along. Just to be sure, I aim to provide both an efficient _and_ robust method of doing so, though that may be a way off. Right now efficiency is my main concern however, so I'm testing in a virtual machine in case there are breakage problems. Much to work on.

Comment: Yeah, I feel for you.  Success though and thanks.  Do you have any of the code published?  Need a tester?  Drop me a comment @Fabby if you need one or where your launchpad is. (I tried ~forrest-carrol, but to no avail)

Comment: @ForrestCarroll if you're willing to code for this, then please try to make `apt` itself do this and fix that bug.

Comment: @muru This is not a 'bug,' per se. It is a non-existent feature. I am interested in making use of the capabilities of aria2 and axel as well, which make it easier to write a wrapper than include either calls or source from either. I will, however, look into doing this. I realize that just such a modification would be useful for many and that having to install a separate wrapper is inconvenient.

Comment: @Fabby I have never written a script or program that would be useful for many others. Most of my projects are automation of niche cases, or small tools that are useful for very odd things. As such, I have no launchpad. After I have a working initial revision, I will create a github repo where bugs can be worked out. When it is sufficiently stable I will create a launchpad for use with it.

Comment: :) I'm sure we're going to hear great things of you in the future!  ;-)